# spack-shell failes to start caused by Error initializing SparkContext sometimes

Tags: apache-spark

Sometimes I got the error below when launching  spark-shell, it  happens sometimes, not everytime. Why?

```
[smile@10-149-11-158 ~]$ cd /data/slot0/spark
[smile@10-149-11-158 spark]$ ./bin/spark-shell --master spark://10-149-11-157:7077
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's repl log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults-repl.properties
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel("INFO")
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.5.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
15/11/12 15:52:11 WARN MetricsSystem: Using default name DAGScheduler for source because spark.app.id is not set.
15/11/12 15:52:11 ERROR SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Application has been killed. Reason: Master removed our application: FAILED
15/11/12 15:52:11 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getSchedulingMode(SparkContext.scala:1575)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postEnvironmentUpdate(SparkContext.scala:2154)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
    at $line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:20)
    at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:24)
    at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.org$apache$spark$SparkContext$$assertNotStopped(SparkContext.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.getSchedulingMode(SparkContext.scala:1575)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.postEnvironmentUpdate(SparkContext.scala:2154)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1017)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at <init>(<console>:20)
    at .<init>(<console>:24)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ui.SQLListener.<init>(SQLListener.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(SQLContext.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1028)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
    at <init>(<console>:20)
    at .<init>(<console>:24)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1340)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:974)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:991)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:672)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

<console>:10: error: not found: value sqlContext
       import sqlContext.implicits._
              ^
<console>:10: error: not found: value sqlContext
       import sqlContext.sql
              ^

scala> exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the real reason, I made a mistake in spark-env.sh

```
SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER "
SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=10.149.11.146:2181,10.149.11.147:2181,10.149.11.148:2181"
SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.dir=/vehicle_spark"
export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS
```

It's wrong, it caused my spark cluster did not use zookeeper, the correct configuration shoud be like this.

```
SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS="-Dspark.deploy.recoveryMode=ZOOKEEPER -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.url=10.149.11.146:2181,10.149.11.147:2181,10.149.11.148:2181 -Dspark.deploy.zookeeper.dir=/vehicle_spark"
export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS
```

Also, when connecting to my spark master using spark-slave.sh or spark-shell, use master host name displayed on web ui instead of IP addresses directly, e.g.

> ./sbin/start-slave.sh
>   spark://10-149-11-157:7077,10-149-11-158:7077,10-149-11-159:7077

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this previous question:
[Spark can no longer execute jobs. Executors fail to create directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852946/spark-can-no-longer-execute-jobs-executors-fail-to-create-directory)

Check to make sure your workers have disk space available.  That could explain the inconsistencies.

Comment: My disk space is large and enough, becuase the cluster is new and no spark apps run on it for now.